# Refresh cache for a directive

Tags: angularjs, caching, directive

I have a mini application about the weather forecast. This is the flow for getting the weather information for a location:

1. Search for a location
2. Click on the result list below. The map will update and show a marker.
3. Click on the marker and the info box that displays the weather forecast information will be showed.

I use a directive to generate the infobox inside the map. This is my code:

```
app.directive("todayInfoDirective", function ($compile) {
    return {
        templateUrl: './src/views/infoBox.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.city = scope.$eval(attrs.city);
            console.log(scope.city);
        }
    }
});
```

I tried to console.log data inside this directive (`scope.city`) and I can see there's new data whenever I click the marker of the different location.

I feel that there's a cache and it makes every popup has the same content.

Is there any idea about this problem?

This is the link to my application: [beacots.com/wf/index.html](http://beacots.com/wf/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

It was because of the bug with my service. Previously, it looks like this :

```
app.factory('darkSkySvr', function($http) {
    var promise = null;
    return function(lat, lng) {
        if(promise) {
            return promise;
        }
        else {
            promise = $http({
                cache: false,
                method: 'GET',
                url: 'http://api.thoitiethanoi.dev2.sutunam.com/forecast/' + lat + ',' + lng,
            })
            return promise;
        }
    }
})
```

I updated by this snippet of code:

```
app.factory('darkSkySvr', function ($http) {
    var promise = null;
    return function (lat, lng) {
        promise = $http({
            cache: false,
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://api.thoitiethanoi.dev2.sutunam.com/forecast/' + lat + ',' + lng,
        })
        return promise;
    }
})
```